# Parse from char array to an char pointer in c++

Tags: c++, char, char-pointer

I have a problem in my code. I want to parse a char array to an char pointer;
How can i do it?

Example code :

```
char tmp[1000];
char *temp;

gets(tmp);
```

How can i parse the char tmp into char *temp?

Regards,

Comment: If you are programming in C++, stop using character arrays and pointers for strings. And never ever use `gets`.

Comment: As for your question, what do you mean by "parse the char tmp"? Parse how? Read from standard input into the `tmp` array? Something else?

Comment: You want `temp=tmp;` or `temp=strdup(tmp);`, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, to point `temp` to `tmp`, this should work.

```
char tmp[1000];
char *temp;
temp = &tmp[0];
```

If you want to copy, you may need to do some more work.

Comment: @DanielBoyMarpaung : Then mark the problem as solved. :)